# Google says not structured data when there is structured data

Tags: structured-data

I have ld+json structured data in several of my sites but the Google Console says it can not find the structured data when I click 'Search Appearance->Structured Data'.

Does it take an extraordinarily long time for Google to find the structured data? Is the process different from the test console? I would love to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is valid according to Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http://www.bartonphillips.com).

Google Search Console (AKA Webmaster Tools) can take a while to update their records, especially sections like Structured Data. If their Testing Tool recognises the data you expect it to, then you should be fine as Google begins to reindex your content.